# How explore and download files from web page python3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, pycharm

I have created this GitHub repository with each python version code in case that you guys would like to check the current code.

https://github.com/AndresUrregoAngel/Python3-request/tree/current

I have a script in Python 2 to log in, explore and download a couple of files from a page using lib2 and other modules. I would like to migrate this script to python v3 using request module. Unfortunately, I've not achieved that because I can't keep the session open to explore the page and then download files. Please check the scripts and let me know how could I figure it out.

PythonV2

```
import os
import time
import urllib
import urllib2
import cookielib
import datetime

# Here are your queue names
QUEUES = {'dis0003': ['dis0003-xxxxxxx', 'dis0003-yyyyyy',
                      'dis0003-zzzzzzzz'],
          'dis0006': ['dis0006-xxxxxxx', 'dis0006-yyyyyyyy',
                      'dis0006-zzzzzzzz',
                      'dis0006-mmmmmmm',
                      'dis0006-nnnnnnnnnn']}


# Your admin login and password
LOGIN = "xxx"
PASSWORD = "xxxxx"
ROOT = "https://xxxxx"


# The client have to take care of the cookies.
jar = cookielib.CookieJar()
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(jar))

# POST login query on '/login_handler' (post data are: 'login' and 'password').
req = urllib2.Request(ROOT + "/login_handler",
                      urllib.urlencode({'login': LOGIN,
                                        'password': PASSWORD}))
opener.open(req)

# Set the right accountcode

for accountcode, queues in QUEUES.items():
    req = urllib2.Request(ROOT + "/switch_to/" + accountcode)
    opener.open(req)

    NOW = datetime.datetime.now()
    YEAR = NOW.year
    FROM_MONTH = NOW.month
    TO_MONTH = NOW.month
    FROM_DAY = NOW.day
    TO_DAY = NOW.day

    from_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime(
        YEAR, FROM_MONTH, FROM_DAY).timetuple())
    to_ts = time.mktime(datetime.datetime(
        YEAR, TO_MONTH, TO_DAY).timetuple())

    # Get the CSV and write it to files
    for queue in queues:
        url = "%s/queue/csv/stats/%s/%s/%s" % (
            ROOT, queue, int(from_ts), int(to_ts))
        sections = []
        section = []
        for line in opener.open(urllib2.Request(url)).read().split('\n'):
            if line:
                section.append(line)
            else:
                sections.append(section)
                section = []
        if section:
            sections.append(section)
        for i, section in enumerate(sections):
            open(os.path.join("file", "%s-%d.csv" % (queue, i + 1)),
                 "wb").write('\n'.join(section))
```

Comment: Consider using requests library. It's better

Comment: Yes, I don't know if you had the time to check out my code on GitHub project in there I'm trying to use request but it doesn't work

Comment: I will check it out